# EXCEL: What type of dataset am I working with overall? How to manipulate pivot tables to answer complex relationships between fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, accounting, data-analysis

I am beginning to delve into data analysis via excel and I would like to learn more about the terminology in terms of some data I'm playing with.

I've created a sample data set for mock invoice charges with different products per invoice listed as unique line items. What type of data set is this called? I want to understand so I can dial in my research and questions moving forward. Image link below.

[image]

Now from here, I'm seeking advice on how to answer some complex questions using pivot tables.

1.) Since values like 'week' repeat, how can I get a count of distinct weeks that a customer bought product? (i.e. How many weeks in the year did Customer A buy product?)

2.) Using the data from above, how can I get some average performance analysis for each unique customer by week?

I'm trying to look at data points like:

- Using Customer A's weeks sold, on average how much do they buy a week?
- Using Customer A's products sold, on average how many units of each product do they buy a week?

I appreciate your patience as I'm aware this is poorly worded, I'm fairly new at using these types of forums.

Comment: @FlexYourData Thank you for the embed edit!

Comment: One question per post please. Use the EDIT button to improve and focus your question.

Answer (score 1):

To get a distinct count of weeks by customer, you should use the Power Pivot Data Model because the Distinct Count aggregation method is not available unless you do so.

When you create your pivot table, be sure to check (tick) the "Add this data to Data Model" checkbox.

[image]

Now you can calculate Distinct Count of Week by adding Week to the Values area and then right-clicking the count in the pivot table and selecting 'Distinct Count' from the 'Summarize Values by' sub-menu of the right-click context menu.

[image]

Regarding 'performance analysis', you would first need to define what that means to you or your business and then go about answering the question with that definition in mind.

Average of qty by customer/week:

[image]

Average of product units per customer per week:

[image]

Of course this is barely scratching the surface of what's possible with Pivot Tables and with Power Pivot.

You should also consider:

1. Number formats
2. Table layout - style and orientation
3. Whether or not to include sub-totals
4. Whether or not to include grand totals
5. More complex measures derived from your existing data

I hope this is enough to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I unfortunately do not have access to the data model method as I'm using Excel for Mac. Is there another resource you can suggest that would provide a similar method?

Comment: Only the distinct count will be a problem. Everything else should be fine. For the distinct count, try looking into Power Query to create a secondary view of the data that is unique on customer/week so that a simple count will achieve the same result.